# is it possible to customize values for parameters in SSRS subscriptions?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

I have an SSRS 2008 report where the default parameters values are this:

```
<ReportParameter Name="BegDate">
      <DataType>DateTime</DataType>
      <DefaultValue>
        <Values>
          <Value>=DateAdd("D",-13,DateAdd("D",6-(Weekday(Today)),Today))</Value>
        </Values>
      </DefaultValue>
      <Prompt>BegDate</Prompt>
    </ReportParameter>
    <ReportParameter Name="EndDate">
      <DataType>DateTime</DataType>
      <DefaultValue>
        <Values>
          <Value>=DateAdd("D",-7,DateAdd("D",6-(Weekday(Today)),Today))</Value>
        </Values>
      </DefaultValue>
```

I am trying to create a subscription to this report, but pass different parameter values in here:

[image]

How can I do this? Can I enter formulas in those textboxes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need data driven subscriptions: found exclusively in the enterprise edition of SQL server:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159150.aspx

I worked for a company previous that didn't have the funds (ehm... was too cheap) to get the enterprise edition.  I wound up writing a pretty cool windows service that authenticated against SSRS and then sent out reports using this technique:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155391.aspx

Comment: thanks so much! i think we do have enterprise. how do i check? could i do this instead? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/535c7e0a-75e2-47d0-8b18-60d1e94805a2

Comment: If it's available it's much easier, ... to check your SQL version: in SSMS right click on the server name and select properties, that should tell you.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP1) - 11.0.3321.0 (X64) 
 Nov 14 2012 19:41:38 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2 <X64> (Build 9200: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: does that mean its not enterprise?

Comment: IT seems like sql 2012 sp1, there's no indication of it being anything but the standard: http://technet.microsoft.com/library/cc645993%28SQL.110%29.aspx ,however because the MS versioning model is a bit confusing, I'd check using http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156012.aspx .  If it's there, good, if not well shoot.  Anyways, have a good weekend and good luck with your project.

Comment: thank you so much. i really appreciate your guidance. i think i will try this solution http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/535c7e0a-75e2-47d0-8b18-60d1e94805a2 have you seen this

Comment: As long as you're working with just dates, I believe that should work.  Of course, that approach has its limitations as compared to data-driven subscriptions, or passing in URL params, but it's also a lot easier to implement, so if self-calculating dates based off the execution date is all you need, I'd recommend using it.

Comment: Well, say you have a string of names from a database, you can't "calculate" those values, you have to import them either via code, or via data drive subscriptions.  Make sense?  They're assuming the values are constant and known (I can tell you that q1 starts Jan 1st for example).